# Azure Pipeline Archive fails no such file or directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I am using Azure CI/CD Pipeline. The project is a ASP.NET app (Website project) which builds successfully. The Azure Pipeline Archive fails finding the dir D:/a/_temp/WebAppContent.

I dont know if the "Build Solution" before the "Archive Files" in the pipeline is causing the issue.

Where can I check to make sure the rootFolderOrFile is created before the "Archive Files"?

**YAML**

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive Files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent'
    includeRootFolder: false
```

**ERROR**

```
ls: no such file or directory: D:/a/_temp/WebAppContent
Found 0 files
##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\a\_temp\WebAppContent'
##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\a\_temp\WebAppContent'
Finishing: Archive Files
```

Here is my Pipeline screeshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue finally. See the Pipeline I am using below.

1. Create a new VS Solution and a new Class Library Project
2. Git Commit  to Azure > and Build (success)
3. In new solution > Add Existing Project > Website (this is legacy asp.net app with aspx and aspx.cs pages)
4. In Website, you must add website.publishproj
5. Build locally and Run locally (success)
6. Git Commit again to Azure > some DLL missing
7. Added missing DLL to project using include files
8. Git Commit again to Azure > now DLL are pushed to Git
9. Successful Build in Azure.

The the main issue was I need to create a brand new Solution + Project, then add Existing Website

[image]

**Update:**
I had to delete the default Archive step and re-add from the Find menu

[image]

**Update 2:**
Here is the YAML that is working

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: NuGet - Installer

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: NuGet - Restore
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: VS Build Legacy App publishproj 
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.publishproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: Azure WebApp Publish
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Azure WebApp'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'XXXXXXXX'
    packageForLinux: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Agent.TempDirectory is temporary folder in the agent, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services).

We could package the output file and save them in the specified location via

```
 /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\\"
```

Result:

[image]